# How to use html in Foundation's tooltips?

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to use html in Foundation's tooltips?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. It supports html in the title attribute.

from *foundation.tooltip.js*:

```
create : function ($target) {
  var $tip = $(this.settings.tip_template(this.selector($target), $('<div></div>').html($target.attr('title')).html())),
  ...
```

Breaking that down it creates a new element wrapped in a `div` and the contents of the title attribute are inserted into the `div` using the `html()` method which will convert any markup in the string to html elements.

The following code:

```
<img src="example.png" 
     class="general-infotip has-tip tip-top"  
     data-tooltip 
     title="<b>This is bold</b> This is not" />
```

Will result in a tool tip that looks like

> **This is bold** This is not

Answer (score 3):

In Foundation v6.3+, you can append the attribute data-allow-html="true" to the element to allow html in the tooltip.

For example:

```
<span data-tooltip data-allow-html="true" aria-haspopup="true" 
      class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" 
      title="Fancy word for a <strong>beetle</strong>. <br><br><img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/730481747679432704/uc08_dqy.jpg />">

    Scarabaeus

</span>
```

Here it is working in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jreLnh6/).

For more information, check out the [pull request](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/8527).